# Java - Is calling a synchronized getter function during a synchronized setter function the right way to manipulate a shared variable?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, deadlock, increment

I have several threads trying to increment a counter for a certain key in a not thread-safe custom data structure (which you can image to be similiar to a HashMap). I was wondering what the right way to increment the counter in this case would be.

Is it sufficient to synchronize the increment function or do I also need to synchronize the get operation?

```
public class Example {

private MyDataStructure<Key, Integer> datastructure = new CustomDataStructure<Key, Integer>();

 private class MyThread implements Runnable() {

    private synchronized void incrementCnt(Key key) {
       // from the datastructure documentation: if a value already exists for the given key, the 
       // previous value will be replaced by this value
       datastructure.put(key, getCnt(key)+1); 

       // or can I do it without using the getCnt() function? like this:
       datastructure.put(key, datastructure.get(key)+1));
    }

    private synchronized int getCnt(Key key) {
       return datastructure.get(key);
    }

    // run method...
 }
}
```

If I have two threads t1, t2 for example, I would to something like:

```
t1.incrementCnt();
t2.incrmentCnt();
```

Can this lead to any kind of deadlock? Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: No deadlock, but if this is the only method that writes to cnt you can just do ++cnt from incrementCnt()

Comment: This code doesn't actually compile. You can't apply the `++` operator to a method call. It has to be a variable. This is not a mere nitpick: this sort of thing should tell you that you're doing it wrong, language-wise, even if the thread mechanism is fine, which it isn't.

Comment: Do those reasons include not being allowed to use your own little version of atomicinteger?

Comment: ok sorry I just tried to come up with a simple example that I did not really code. I see that it lacks relevant information to understand the context of my question so I will just edit question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main issue with this code is that it's likely to fail in providing synchronization access to `datastructure`, since accessing code synchronizing on `this` of an inner class. Which is different for different instances of `MyThread`, so no mutual exclusion will happen.

More correct way is to make `datastructure` a `final` field, and then to synchronize on it:

```
private final MyDataStructure<Key, Integer> datastructure = new CustomDataStructure<Key, Integer>();

private class MyThread implements Runnable() {

    private void incrementCnt(Key key) {
        synchronized (datastructure) {
            // or can I do it without using the getCnt() function? like this:
            datastructure.put(key, datastructure.get(key)+1));
        }
    }
```

As long as all data access is done using `synchronized (datastructure)`, code is thread-safe and it's safe to just use `datastructure.get(...)`. There should be no dead-locks, since deadlocks can occur only when there's more than one lock to compete for.

Comment: All data access is done through the incrementCnt() function so I will go with your suggestion. Thank you for your help

Comment: is declaring the datastructure as `final` really necessary here or just good practice? the datastructure object will not be rebound to reference another object.

Comment: @SeanKw If you 200% sure reference won't be overwritten, you can omit `final`, but just for being on a safer side, I would always use `final` in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer told you, you should synchronize on your data structure, rather than on the thread/runnable object. It is a common mistake to try to use synchronized methods in the thread or runnable object. Synchronization locks are instance-based, not class-based (unless the method is static), and when you are running multiple threads, this means that there are actually multiple thread instances.

It's less clear-cut about Runnables: you could be using a single instance of your Runnable class with several threads. So in principle you *could* synchronize on it. But I still think it's bad form because in the future you may want to create more than one instance of it, and get a really nasty bug.

So the general best practice is to synchronize on the actual item that you are accessing.

Furthermore, the design conundrum of whether or not to use two methods should be solved by moving the whole thing into the data structure itself, if you can do so (if the class source is under your control). This is an operation that is confined to the data structure and applies only to it, and doing the increment outside of it is not good encapsulation. If your data structure exposes a synchronized `incrementCnt` method, then:

- It synchronizes on itself, which is what you wanted.
- It can use its own private fields directly, which means you don't actually need to call a getter and a setter.
- It is free to have the implementation changed to one of the atomic structures in the future if it becomes possible, or add other implementation details (such as logging increment operations separately from setter access operations).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation about synchronization locks. The data structure is unfortunately not under my control that's why I was looking for a thread-safe way to access it. What I needed was a data structure like a ConcurrentHashMap but for specific reasons I have to stick to the custom data structure.